# How does one return html from an AngularJS function?

Tags: html, angularjs, function, controller

I'm brand new creating AngularJS style code.  I'm attempting to recreate an existing site in AngularJS format.

I finally figured out how to make an app/controller in an external file and give the controller functions.  I can then have those functions return variables, particularly strings, to fill in information in my .html file, but when I use html tags, they are used as literals in the .html.

I'm trying to find out how to fill my html template in a similar manner, but with the html working.

In other JS formats, I can write to the document/response, or at least have the function return a value to then have the original JS/HTML write that return value as html.

I'm attempting something similar here in the footer, but the Footer() has a string that needs to be displayed on two lines.

Example code to follow (I'll edit it down to the important bits):
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script language="JavaScript" src="./Universal.js" runat="server"></script>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <link href="./Main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body id="idBody" ng-app="Universal">
        <table id="idTableMain">
            <tr id="idFooterRow">
                <td id="idFooterMain" colspan="3">
                    <p id="idFooterContent" ng-controller="UniversalController">
                        {{Footer()}}
                    </p>
                    <p id="idFooterManagement" ng-controller="UniversalController">
                        {{WebMaster()}}
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

App/Controller:

```
var Universal = angular.module("Universal", []);

Universal.controller("UniversalController", ['$scope', function ($scope)
    {
        $scope.Footer = function()
        {
            $scope.vResult = "© Copyright 2012 All rights reserved<br>";    
            $scope.vResult += "House That Kamurai Built";
            return $scope.vResult;
        };

        $scope.WebMaster = function()
        {
            $scope.vResult = "Website managed by Kamurai.";
            return $scope.vResult;
        };
    }]);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `ng-bind-html` to display HTML on page, but before doing that you should make that `html` as trusted by calling `$sce.trustAsHtml` method.

```
$scope.Footer = function() {
    $scope.vResult = "© Copyright 2012 All rights reserved<br>";
    $scope.vResult += "House That Kamurai Built";
    return $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.vResult);
};
```

**Html**

```
<p id="idFooterContent" 
  ng-controller="UniversalController" 
  ng-bind-html="Footer()">
</p>
```

[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/dEgPIodkn6E6JQF7nxsQ?p=preview)

> **Suggestion:** You could have placed `ng-controller="UniversalController"` directly on table instead of
>   placing twice on page. I don't know what special case you had, that
>   led you there.

Comment: Like I said, I'm still new to this, so I'm trying to walk through this slowly.  I put the controller on the one element, did that and then added the second, so I haven't got around to how to consolidate the controllers yet.

I know I'm going to have at least one other controller eventually, but I'll probably have to post another question about keeping them from overlapping.

Comment: Thank you, but I must be doing something else wrong, I can't seem to get anything to return with your suggestion.  I'll keep looking into it and mark this as the answer if I can get it working.

Comment: @Kamurai did you looked at the plunker demo link.. It might help you understand it in better way

Comment: And bingo, I hadn't looked at your .js file on plunket and forgot to add $sce like so: Universal.controller("UniversalController", ['$scope', '$sce', function ($scope, $sce)